# checkbox permission[access] validation not working Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am setting up some checkboxs and the name on check box is `name="permission[access][]"`

I cannot get codeigniter validation to work with that will not display the validation error message

**How can I get it to work with the name** `name="permission[access][]"`

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Post_test extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {

    $data['action'] = site_url('post_test');

    $ignore = array(
        'common/dashboard',
        'common/footer',
        'common/header'
    );

    $data['permissions'] = array();

    $files = glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/*/*.php');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $part = explode('/', dirname($file));

        $permission = end($part) . '/' . basename($file, '.php');

        if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
            $data['permissions'][] = $permission;
        }
    }

    if ($this->input->post('permission[access]') !== FALSE) {
        $data['access'] = $this->input->post('permission[access]');
    } else {
        $data['access'] = array();
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('permission[access]', 'Permission Access', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

    $this->load->view('post_test.tpl', $data);

    } else {

        var_dump($_POST);

    }
}

}
```

View:

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
<form action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
<?php foreach ($permissions as $permission) { ?>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<?php if (in_array($permission, $access)) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" checked="checked" />
<?php echo $permission; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" />
<?php echo $permission; ?>
<?php } ?>
</label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="buttons clearfix">
<div class="pull-left"></div>
<div class="pull-right">
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: if you `var_dump($_POST);die();` at the begining of your function, do see what you need ?

Comment: Do not understand question all it is i that the validation errors are not showing if do not check any boxes. If I check boxes then it vardump `array(1) { ["permission"]=> array(1) { ["access"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(16) "common/post_test" [1]=> string(13) "common/step_3" [2]=> string(13) "common/step_4" } } }`

Comment: Indeed I missunderstood. Then, it's probably because you forgot to set `<?php echo form_error('permission[access]'); ?>` in your view

Comment: If you look at top of view you will see `<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>`

Comment: Yes, I saw. That just sets the delimiters for the form error message, not the errors themselfs. EDIT : yes you're right, after reading the CI doc. it should work this way too.

Comment: How would I use the delimiters I never used them before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71463/discussion-between-mustang83-and-adrienxl).